# RVM bundler installed ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I get to work with a new project and it's based on ruby 1.8.7, I'm using rvm to manage my ruby versions and I have installed 1.8.7 and 1.9.2.

The thing is when I do:

```
rvm use 1.8.7
```

and try to run:

```
bundle install
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

I've installed bundler 5 times and even after that it says it's not installed. What can cause this? Bundle even shows up at my gem list.

**update from comments:**

The ouput of the which ruby && which gem is:

```
/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby
/home/username/.rvm/bin/gem
```

Output of "env | grep -iE 'ruby|rvm|gem' | sort":

```
GEM_HOME=/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global
GEM_PATH=/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global
IRBRC=/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/.irbrc
MY_RUBY_HOME=/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371
PATH=/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/bin:/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin:/home/username/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-1.8.7-p371
rvm_bin_path=/home/username/.rvm/bin
rvm_delete_flag=0
rvm_path=/home/username/.rvm
rvm_prefix=/home/username
rvm_ruby_string=ruby-1.8.7-p371
rvm_sticky_flag=1
rvm_use_flag=1
rvm_version=1.17.7 (stable)
```

**Unistalled and installed 1.8.7 via RVM**
ran:

```
rvm install 1.8.7 --verify-downloads 1
```

and it worked.

Comment: You have some disconnect between your path, what RVM think's it's doing, what ruby/gem executable is getting used, or some other strange environment issue. Try running 'which gem' and 'which ruby'.

Did you reload your terminal window after installing rvm?

Comment: I've edited my question with the output of the commands and yes I did reload the terminal. Rvm has been installed in my pc for a long time.

Comment: can you add `env | grep -iE 'ruby|rvm|gem' | sort`

Comment: Added that output to the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're probably running the wrong version of `gem`.  In my RVM setup, using the shell command overrides recommended with RVM (`source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or another suitable startup file), `gem` is normally a shell function.  It does some RVM magic under the covers and then runs the real `gem` command.  In my case, both `ruby` and `gem` run out of the same version directory:

```
/home/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
/home/jim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/gem
```

Make sure you're sourcing the RVM startup script.

Your `PATH` looks ok.  Make sure you have a `/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/gem` command.  If not, you may have to reinstall ruby-1.8.7.

Running `rvm current` will show which Ruby version and gemset are being used.  Make sure there's a `gem` in the path that matches the Ruby version.

Comment: You are right, there is no gem command on my ruby 1.8.7 folder, I uninstalled and installed it again, but nothing, the output of the installation is now on the question.

Comment: Thanks you were totally right, when re-installing the output told to add '--verify-downloads 1' to the command to install the version I wanted, and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320

use this and remember close all terminal 
and in edit-> profile preferences--> title and command -->> check (Run command as login shell)